# NaN in else statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Please I can't figure out why is function returning me `NaN` in `else` statement.

The goal is to get mean of the all goals scored in whole season by team without the last match. If there is only one match in the season, I want to return goals scored in that match.

DF:

```
HOME   AWAY    SEASON HOME_GOALS AWAY_GOALS ...
Team 1 Team 2  2020   1          1
Team 3 Team 4  2020   2          3
Team 1 Team 3  2019   2          1
Team 1 Team 4  2020   3          2
```

Expected output:

```
HOME   AWAY    SEASON HOME_GOALS AWAY_GOALS HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON
Team 1 Team 2  2020   1          1          2 (1+3)/2
Team 3 Team 4  2020   2          3          2
Team 1 Team 3  2019   4          1          4
Team 1 Team 4  2020   3          2          2 (1+3)/2

df.insert(loc = 1, column ="HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON", value = 99.9 )

def last_season(team):
        if len(team["HOME_GOALS"] > 1):
            return team["HOME_GOALS"].iloc[:-1].mean()
        else:
            return team["HOME_GOALS"].iloc[0]

df = df.set_index(["HOME", "SEASON"])
df["HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON"] = df.groupby(["HOME", "SEASON"]).apply(last_season)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: show a sample of the content in `df`

Answer (score 1):

Why you complicate your life? If there's only 1 match, the mean will be simply its score.

No need for `if`-`else`.

So your command

```
df["HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON"] = df.groupby(["HOME", "SEASON"]).apply(last_season)
```

replace with

```
df["HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON"] = df.groupby(["HOME", "SEASON"])["HOME_GOALS"].mean()
```

(and remove your function definition).

Comment: The thing is that I want to get the mean without the last match (if there is 2+ matches). THerefore I use .iloc[:-1]. So if there is only one match, then I get NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
def last_season(team):
        if len(team["HOME_GOALS"] > 1):
            return team["HOME_GOALS"].iloc[:-1].mean()
        else:
            return team["HOME_GOALS"].iloc[0]
```

use

```
def last_season(team):
        if len(team) > 1):
            return team.iloc[:-1].mean()
        else:
            return team.iloc[0]
```

and instead of `.apply()` use `.agg()` - only to the `"HOME_GOALS"` column:

```
df["HOME_GOALS_LAST_SEASON"] = df.groupby(["HOME", "SEASON"])["HOME_GOALS"].agg(last_season)
```

The `.agg()` method receives successively individual columns (a series) as its parameter, while `.apply()` the whole dataframe.

Comment: Still returns NaN when there is only one match.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't provide a sample dataframe, so I didn't test the code. Without it, I see no sense to continue.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed first comment. I will edit original post.